# Why is my nested loop producing the same output?

Tags: c++

I am writing a program to find a 4-digit address. The program should continually allow the user to enter digits until the correct answer is solved. Additional parameters are:

- All four digits are different
- The digit in the thousands place is three times the digit in the tens
  place
- The number is odd
- The sum of the digits is 27

With the program I've written so far it gives me the same output of "address is correct" no matter the input is. Trying to figure out what I am doing wrong, but no success. This is the code I've written so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int const Address = 9837;
    int input;
    char Y;
    char N;
    int sum;
    int even;
    int i;

    cout << "Please enter a 4-digit number." << endl;
    cin >> input;

    {
        while (input = Y || N)
        {
            if (input = Y)
                cout << "Please enter a 4-digit number" << endl;
            else if (input = N)
                cout << "Good Bye!!" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        while (input != Address && Y && N)
        {
            if (sum = input == !27);
            cout << "Not a valid address - the sum of the digits is not 27" << endl;
            if (input % 2 == 0)
                cout << "Not a valid address - the number is even." << endl;
        }
        input = Address;
        cout << "Address is correct." << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `input = Y || N` doesn't remotely do what you think it does. It says: "assign to `input` the result of expression `Y || N`" And since both `Y` and `N` are uninitialized variables, the program exhibits undefined behavior. No offense intended, but this code makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

- You include `<cmath>` and `<string>` but you don't use anything from that headers.
- Declare/define variables as close to where they're used/needed.
- You are using the variables `N` and `Y` uninitialized. They contain an indeterminate value (=garbage). If `char` happens to be `unsigned`, reading an indeterminate value (an uninitialized `(unsigned) char`) under a few certain conditions is allowed. But you use `N` and `Y` in a way where reading their values causes undefined behaviour.
- The variables `even` and `i` are never used.
- With `cin >> input;` you try to extract an `int`eger from standard input. If the user would enter `Y` or `N` or anything else that is not an `int`eger, extraction would fail. You need two different ways to get the users input: 1 to let the user enter his guessed number and 1 to let the user choose if he wants to play again.
- You introduce a block (`{`) after `cin >> input;` that serves no purpose.
- `while (input = Y || N)` ... Comparison is done with the operator `==` in C++ (and C) but `=` is assignment. The expression `input = Y || N` assigns the result of `Y || N` to `input` but since `Y` and `N` are uninitialized and chances that both contain the value `0` is quite low (`0 || 0` would evaluate to `false`), input will almost always be `1` (`true` converted to an `int` is `1`) and the loop will always execute.
  Actually, reading the values of `Y` and `N` causes undefined behaviour because they're uninitialized. Theoretically (since the compiler knows that `Y` and `N` have indeterminate value), it can generate any code it likes.
- Within the first `while`-loop:

  > ```
  >    if (input = Y)  // is again an assignment, not a test for equality
  >        cout << "Please enter a 4-digit number" << endl;
  >    else if (input = N)  // again
  >        cout << "Good Bye!!" << endl;
  >    return 0;  // will always exit the program, no matter the value of input
  > ```
- In case all hell breaks loose and `N` and `Y` are both `0` by chance and thus the 2nd `while`-loop is reached, it is sure, that `input` is `0` (because otherwise the controlled statement of the 1st `while`-loop would have been executed and exited the program by `return 0;`). When `input` equals `0` it isn't equal to `Address` so `input != Address` yields `true` but since we know that `N` and `Y` are `0` (`false`) and `true && false` gives `false`, the controlled statement of the 2nd `while`-loop doesn't get executed.
- I'll skip the contents of the controlled statement of the 2nd `while`-loop. Sufficive to say, they don't do what you think they do.
- > ```
  > input = Address;  // that assignment serves no purpose
  > ```
- > ```
  > cout << "Address is correct." << endl;
  > ```

  is the output you always get when the variables `Y` and `N` are `0`, which might happen (especially when running debug-code).

Please, stay away from the source you're currently learning C++ from. Get a good textbook and start over.

Answer (score 0):

Is the piece of code you have captured here missing something or incomplete? I see that Y, N and sum are not assigned any value and thus all conditions checks fail... Eventually it will display "Address is correct" always...

Comment: *are not assigned any value and thus all conditions checks fail...* – `Y` and `N` have indeterminate value. Nobody can tell for sure if the condition of the 1st `while`-loop is `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

A few things you need to know:

- You should assign values to things before calling them
- You should read about the difference between = and ==
- If you want multiple inputs, your `cin >> input;` should be in your while loop
- Your code is not well indented at some places
- You are declaring a `i` integer, but you are never using it.

In other words: your compiler must be giving you a LOT of warnings. Did you look at them?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that = and == are totally different. 
= means an assignment. eg: int x = 100; means put the value of 100 into the variable x.
== means comparison or (is equal to). eg: if (x == 100), means if x has the value 100.

Also, If you're trying to make a choice variable for Yes or No,
You should do it this way:
char ans;
if (ans == 'Y' || ans == 'N")

Since your input variable is an int, and your choice variable is a char, your while statement is not valid.

Comment: *Since your input variable is an int, and your choice variable is a char, your while statement is not valid.* – said statement `while (input = Y || N)` is perfectly valid.